# how do I tell if a class is equal to or extends another class (java)

Tags: java

so I am writing a minecraft mod in which I have successfully added a pistol which works with allot of support classes that handle things like raytracing and sounds and GUI overlays. while the pistol works perfectly, I would like to add support for other mods to add their own weapons using my weapon class as a base class. My problem is how do I get my support classes to know if an item class is actually a custom class that extends my weapon class. Basically what I need to be able to tell is if an instance of a class can be cast to my weapon class for processing using my weapon's base data and functions (note that I am given an instance of the Item class which my WeponItem class extends). Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: it's always welcome to use instanceof when we what to check the class instace. So you can use   

if(object instanceof yourCheckInstance calss)

Comment: I'm wondering if you're really asking (or will soon ask) "How do I find all classes which are sub-types of my class (in the current class path)?"

Comment: There is some discussion as to why you need to use instanceof at all? Are you going to check all objects in the world if they are instances of your baseclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(object instanceof SomeClass)
```

Answer (score 4):

See [15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

```
if(someObject instanceof SomeClass)
```

Learn from [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), learn from the best.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) to check your type.

Following example may help you

```
class InstanceofDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Parent obj1 = new Parent();
    Parent obj2 = new Child();

    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Parent: "
        + (obj1 instanceof Parent));
    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Child: "
        + (obj1 instanceof Child));
    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof MyInterface: "
        + (obj1 instanceof MyInterface));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Parent: "
        + (obj2 instanceof Parent));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Child: "
        + (obj2 instanceof Child));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof MyInterface: "
        + (obj2 instanceof MyInterface));
}
}

class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent implements MyInterface {}
interface MyInterface {}

Output:

obj1 instanceof Parent: true
obj1 instanceof Child: false
obj1 instanceof MyInterface: false
obj2 instanceof Parent: true
obj2 instanceof Child: true
obj2 instanceof MyInterface: true
```

Example from reference.

Answer (score 3):

instanceOf should help you do the trick.

```
if(yourObject instanceof OtherClass)
```

If you have a object of a unknown class you can also use .getClass() on that object to find out the class. You can also compare two object like this:

```
if(yourObject instanceof OtherObject)
```

There are also some other things you should be aware of: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31

Answer (score 2):

You can check if class is instance of your base class:

```
if (objA instanceof baseObj){

// objA is instance of baseObj

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
Pistol  pistol  = new Pistol ();

if(pistol instanceof Weapon )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: You really should not do that. You should instead define an interface called Weapon, which all weapons then must implement and which then contains all the methods your program need.

Comment: both interfaces and abstract classes are appropriate techniques for different circumstances

Comment: True, but it is normally a sign of big problems if you need to use instanceof. But since this is a minecraft mod, there might be special limitations which require it.

Comment: I'm somewhat uncertain why instanceof is even nessissary also and agree that appropriate use is rare, but an interface *could* still require an instanceof check if an abstract class version does

Comment: While it is true that almost all `instanceof` checks can be coerced into polymorphic behavior in a rich object model, it is not always the case that you have complete control over the inheritance hierarchy that you are working with/from. It is in these cases where `instanceof` is still necessary.